# XNA Game (for WP7) can be run in debug mode only, black screen and quit in running mode after deployed

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

Recently after quite some time working on my personal game project for WP7, I found that it can run in debug mode only. The game shows black screen and quit in aroud 5 seconds, if I run it directly on phone after it is deploy, without touching debug in VS.

What I'm doubting is the game took so long for start up so it automatically quit as WP7's OS considers the game as unresponsive.

So any idea? Thanks in advance.

Update: when I look at the XDE Console, the follow messages are shown https://edventure.ntu.edu.sg/bbcswebdav/users/pham0050/CIDP/Capture.PNG

Comment: Do you use any Debug flag in the code? Try to catch all exceptions and print them.

Comment: There is no exception in debug mode, my game run perfectly under debug mode, without causing any exception.

Answer (score 0):

What is the red badger XPF license, and why does it seem to print that message until the error? might be related to that